# Why is $X^2+1$ reducible in $F_2$?

Tags: ring-theory, coding-theory

One of my modules contains parts of ring theory which I have not done in over a year. So I appreciate this question may seem very basic as I am giving myself a crash course in ring theory by studying examples.

Why is $X^2+1$ reducible in $F_2$?
And why is $X^2-X+1$ irreducible in $F_2$?

Comment: Because $(X+1)^2 \equiv X^2 + 1 \pmod 2$. And because there is no way of factorising $X^2-X+1$ modulo 2

Comment: Hint. A quadratic polynomial is irreducible if and only if it has no roots. Check each for roots.

Comment: Because $2x\equiv 0\pmod 2$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is reducible since it has a root in the field...Note : don't use the converse that if a polynomial doesn't have a root in the field  means it is irreducible.This is not the case always.But is true only if you have a polynomial of degree 2 or 3.

Comment: How do you check if it has root in the field? e.g how do you check if $X^2 +1$ has a root in $F_2$?

Comment: How do you check for roots of a polynomial in $R$....do it the same way the only difference being that your choices get reduced from uncountable to merely 2....and don't forget the operation is modulo 2.so whatever remainder you get you modulo2 it

Comment: But $X^2+1$ has no real roots though?

Comment: Thats the whole point you are not in the real field your are in $Z_2$ there is a root in it.namely $1$

Comment: Right I understand, so $X^2=-1$ but $-1 mod2=1$ so $X^2=1$. hence we have one root $X=1$

Comment: Yes -1 is congruent 1(mod2)

Comment: Is their a quick way to find a polynomial which is not irreducible over any arbitrary field?

Answer (score 4):

$$\forall\;\text{ prime}\;\;p\;,\;\;(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p\pmod p\implies (x^2+1)=(x+1)^2\pmod2$$

As for $\;x^2-x+x^2+x+1\pmod 2\;$ : check this quadratic has not roots in $\;\Bbb F_2\;$ and is thus irreducible (because a polynomial of degree less than four is irredicible over a field iff it has no roots in that field)

Answer (score 2):

$X^2 + 1$ is reducible because it is the product of smaller degree polynomials: $(x+1)(x+1) = x^2 + 1$.

Now, **if** $X^2 -X  + 1 $ was reducible, then it would be the product of two linear factors. That means that the polynomial would have a root in $F_2$. But, you can check (easily) that the polynomial does not have any roots.

Answer (score 0):

for $x^2+1$, can you explain why (over $F_2$) $x^2+1$ is the same as $x^2-1$? And the standard factorization of $x^2-1$ is...?
This shows $x^2-1$ is reducible.

As for $x^2-x+1$, note that quadratic (say $q(x)$) over a field $K$ is irreducible if and only if $q$ has no roots in $K$. Let $q=x^2-x+1$. What is $q(0)$? What is $q(1)$? Can we say (over $F_2$) $q$ has no roots?

Comment: This is a 7 years old question with several answers already. No need to post another one, in particular when it is already covered by the other answers.

Comment: what does this add to the previous answers?